# omnet++ Installation Problems

Tags: omnet++

I am Installing Omnet++ 4.6 version in windows environment. But while giving the command "make" I am getting the following error. Could somebody help me to get rid of this ?

make
make MODE=release
      0 [main] make 10976 child_info_fork::abort: E:\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin\msys-gmp-10.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x150000) != child(0x8A0000)
make: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: Why are you trying to install 4.6 instead of the latest version?

Comment: I am working on codes which is actually not being accepted in some latest versions. Hence I preferred this.